# Koan vs KOAN Sound

Tags: electronic-music

Does anyone know if Koan (the ones who produced the albums "Argonautica" and "When the Silence is Speaking") is the same group/artist as KOAN Sound? Or are these two different artists?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Koan Sound is British project, while Koan is Russian one. If you want to find more info about them you can start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOAN_Sound and https://www.patreon.com/koanmsk (links to Koan Sound and Koan respectively).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Every time I search for KOAN on any music platform the search algorithm always spits out content by Koan Sound, this was very confusing as I was wondering if they were the same group/band. your answer cleared it up.